# Neo4j simple `CASE` expression

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to generate a table which contains the name of the sender, name of the receiver and the number of messages sent by the sender as count (if any, otherwise 0) using neo4j `CASE` construct but I am not getting the intended result. Here is my query:

```
MATCH(e:Employee{key:1}),(b:Employee), 
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)-[r:Message]->(b)
RETURN e.name, DISTINCT b.name,
CASE
WHEN (e)-[r:Message]->(b)
THEN COUNT(r)
ELSE 0 END AS Messages
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, you can directly use this in the result part: `size((e)-[r:Message]->(b)) AS Messages`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you do not need this `CASE WHEN` to achieve your goal. If you need the `count()` of `:Message` relationships between `e` and `b` nodes you can simply return the count of it:

```
MATCH(e:Employee{key:1}),(b:Employee)
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)-[r:Message]->(b)
RETURN DISTINCT e.name, b.name, COUNT(r) as Messages
```

This query will return zero in the `COUNT(r)` if no relationship exists between `e` and `b` nodes.

Comment: I see..Thank you Bruno...really amazing!